# json parsing issue in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having trouble with ajax/jquery in codeigniter.

In an Html page I've a button, when it's pressed
the following handler is called.

Handler of button press:

```
function postMessage(e) {
    var postUrl = 'http://localhost/myProject/index.php/main/post_message';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: postUrl,
        success: successfulPost,
        dataType: "text"
    });      
}
```

ajax callback:

```
function successfulPost(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    document.write(data[0].hello);
}
```

service function inside **main** controller:

```
function post_message() {   
    echo "[{\"hello\":\"world\"}]";
    return;  
}
```

The problem is that JSON.parse() doesn't seem to get his job done.

These functions are pretty simple, so I'm starting thinking maybe there's a problem with codeigniter?

EDIT:

what is curious is that if I put exactly the same json string into JSON.parse()
it gets parsed, the problem is when the service function passes it.

EDIT:

counting the numbers of characters of the json string it should be 13
but I get 17...

Edit:

I'm now recognising that even though echoing is done properly
there are strange characters leading the body of the HTTP response...
something such as new lines \0 or tabs
anyone has any clue why?

Comment: Data type in the ajax call is text and it might be returning you the text,change this and see if that solves your problem.Json parse won't work correctly if you are not getting json data and as you have written text in datatype it will send you the text output.

Comment: what is your browser ?, did you checked the console log (f12) ?, JSON.parse is only supported on modern browsers, use $.parseJSON() instead

Comment: no,originally it was "json" and successfulPost wasn't getting even called because the parse error was generated before, I put "text" this way successfullPost gets called and I can make some debugging using alert.

Comment: my browser i google Chrome, I just tried to do as you suggest but it's exactly the same:SyntaxError

Comment: are you sending html or json data from this page in url,have you checked that?If you see step be step process,you tell ajax call to expect data in 'dataFormat' type which is the kind of data you are getting from this url.It might be html or json data depending on this targetUrl.If is json data then only you can parse it with JSON parse else it will not be parsed.

Comment: the content-type sent form the server is Content-Type: text/html

Comment: also I'm using fiddler for web debugging and It parses the json string fine..

Comment: chrome won't let you do ajax on Localhost because it considers it cross origin.  throw it in firefox and it should work fine if you need to test it.

Comment: I' already wrote some ajax code  for chrome and it works fine even from  localhost, maybe codeigniter is the proble,

Comment: same parse error even with firefox

Comment: try this in you php file echo json_parse("Hello"); die; instead of your current echo return

Comment: it does not recognise the function json_parse()

Comment: i meant php function for encoding the php.Dude I acknowledge my mistake but you get to google a little.You might have stumbled upon something like json_encode("Hello").Message was that you have to send the json data.

Comment: I would have to create an object or an associative array and then let json_encode() encode it, but I don't think it's the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header in PHP:

```
$data = array("hello" => "world");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

[Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Comment: thanks for your help, but that'not working, as I said the problem is that in the leading characters of the http body response there are tabs and \0, I don't know why they are there, but I think this could be a bug of codeIgniter or at least of the version I'm using, any help in this sense is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call most of the times you just need to stick with `dataType: "JSON"` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    success: successfulPost,
    dataType: "JSON"
});
```

Then in your controller you just have your normal `$_POST` array as a key-value pairs or if you are using codeigniter you got your `$this->input->post('whatever')`, anyways after completing your logic and before echoing you need to use `json_encode($data_array)` like this:

```
function post_message()
{
    $data = array();
    $data['hello'] = "world";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
function successfulPost(data) {
    // data = JSON.parse(data); not needed
    document.write(data.hello);
    // data.hello = world
}
```